# Definite articles - introducing the notation

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is the first option correct, please?

> The components A, B, C will be denoted by indices 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

> The components A, B, C will be denoted by **the** indices 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

Comment: The sentence will be meaningful only if you have previously indicated in the correct order what 1,2 and 3 refer to.

Comment: The article is *optional* in your cited context (but it wouldn't *normally* be included). Note that in superficially very similar contexts, such as *Pictures A, B, and C  can be described by **the** words "happy", "sad", and "horrific"* it's *not* idiomatic to discard the article. So I'm not sure whether it's possible to define even a "general principle" here - there's certainly no "fixed rule" to tell you whether you do or don't "need" an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option sounds good to me.

Comment: You really should explain why that is. :)

Comment: The definite article could be used if for example it was previously mentioned that the 1, 2, and 3 indices have some sort of special meaning. Actually the article is not necessary for  a plural noun.  I assume the question concerns programming. lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "b", "c", "d" - they will be denoted by indices 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

Comment: You need to delete that paragraph and use the edit button to revise your answer. :)

Comment: Yes, it has no special meaning, thanks a lot.